# How to use fetchMessages() to fetch a certain amount of messages then send them in a certain way?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

What I would like to do is to take information from resolving a promise from `fetchMessages()` and then being able to go through the collection it gives and ***then*** being able to send certain pieces.

For example, the bot will list 10 messages looking like `GalaxyDJx#2462: hi` by, if possible, finding the information (e.g. username, discriminator, message content) and then having each piece of information set to its own variable such as `var uname`, `var discrm`, and `var msgcnt`.

The information I got from one message is below and all I really need is the member's username, discriminator, and get the message content that they sent.

```
'439129579567972353' => Message {
  channel: TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    id: '411925734970490880',
    name: 'galaxys-bot-testing',
    position: 3,
    parentID: '394174705655087104',
    permissionOverwrites: [Object],
    topic: '',
    nsfw: false,
    lastMessageID: '439131920736059402',
    guild: [Object],
    messages: [Object],
    _typing: Map {},
    lastMessage: [Object]
  },
  id: '439129579567972353',
  type: 'DEFAULT',
  content: '<@436985225546039337> fetch',
  author: User {
    id: '311283024312532993',
    username: 'GalaxyDJx',
    discriminator: '2462',
    avatar: 'IgnoreThis',
    bot: false,
    lastMessageID: '439131920736059402',
    lastMessage: [Object]
  },
  member: GuildMember {
    guild: [Object],
    user: [Object],
    _roles: [Array],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: null,
    joinedTimestamp: 1518280794719,
    lastMessageID: '439131920736059402',
    lastMessage: [Object]
  },
  pinned: false,
  tts: false,
  nonce: undefined,
  system: false,
  embeds: [],
  attachments: Collection {},
  createdTimestamp: 1524767050402,
  editedTimestamp: null,
  reactions: Collection {},
  mentions: MessageMentions {
    everyone: false,
    users: [Object],
    roles: Collection {},
    _content: '<@436985225546039337> fetch',
    _client: [Object],
    _guild: [Object],
    _members: null,
    _channels: null
  },
  webhookID: null,
  hit: null,
  _edits: []
}
```

I got this information from using this code.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 1}));

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`TextChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) returns a Promise, you don't need to use `Promise.resolve()`, store the returned value and all that stuff: you can just do this:

```
message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 1}).then(console.log);
//       this returns a Promise          |     Here you're using Promise.then()
```