# How to fetch x amount of Messages

Tags: node.js, fetch, discord, discord.js

I would like to fetch x amount of messages to later send them a rich embed. How can I fetch that amount?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use fetchMessages() to fetch a certain amount of messages then send them in a certain way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051300/how-to-use-fetchmessages-to-fetch-a-certain-amount-of-messages-then-send-them)

Comment: But how can I then retrieve the messages to send them? Can you give me a code sample, please?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `TectChannel.fetchMessages()` it returns a Promise that is resolved with a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of messages.
To send them in a RichEmbed, you have to either use [`.array()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) and transform the Collection into an Array or use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach). I'll show you how to use the Array.

```
let x = 10, // x should be form 0 to 25
  embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle('Fecthed messages');

channel.fetchMessages({ limit: x }).then(messages => {
  let arr = messages.array(); // you get the array of messages

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // you loop through them
    let curr = arr[i],
      str = curr.content.trim();
    if (str.length > 2048) str = str.substring(0, 2045) + '...';
    // if the content is over the limit, you cut it

    embed.addField(curr.author, str); // then you add it to the embed
  }

}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Ohh, with message.array(). Thank you very much! :)

Comment: But, is there a way to get multiple messages to display or just one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Tester3
This should display `x` messages (declared at the top of my code). Are you sure there is more than one message in the channel you're fetching them from?

Comment: Sorry, for the late answer, but yes

Comment: Have you tried seeing if it loops correctly? Have you tried checking how many messages it collects? Have you tried checking you are not sending the embed before it's ready? You have to give me more infos if you want me to help you, since I can't debug your code from here

Answer (score 1):

The following is the example given in the discord.js docs:

```
// Get messages
channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 10 })
  .then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

This will retrieve the latest 10 messages from the text channel.

You can read more about the method and its options here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages

Comment: Nice, thank you very, I already tried that, but actually also wanted to send the fetched messages in a RichEmbed :/

Comment: @Tester3 I think you have an answer to the question "How to get the top x results"  Maybe you need another question for how to send a richEmbed?

Comment: Nah, I know that, I need the fetchMessages as well, not just the Size of the messages